# Word that means "to be oblivious to" but not on purpose?

Tags: single-word-requests

I searched for [be oblivious to](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/be%20oblivious%20to) in Thesaurus but it only has synonyms of ignore (to disregard intentionally). I'm looking for something more silimiar to "to not to know".

Example sentence:

> Truth be told, he __ the answer himself.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use oblivious ? Maybe _miss_ fits here ?

Comment: "didn't know", "didn't see", "didn't perceive", "couldn't discern"

Comment: oblivious makes no assumption of purpose in either direction.

Comment: [**unaware, oblivious,** clueless, incognizant, innocent, insensible, nescient, oblivious, unacquainted, ignorant, unconscious, uninformed, unknowing, unmindful, unwitting,...](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unaware)

Comment: Interestingly, in the various senses of *oblivious* and *oblivion* the OED does not include any which suggest *intent*. They relate to *not knowing* and *forgetfulness* from where the root comes -  *Etymology:  < classical Latin oblīviōsus forgetful, producing forgetfulness < oblīviōn- , oblīviō oblivion n.  + -ōsus -ous suffix. Compare Middle French  oblivieux that forgets easily (mid 15th cent. as obliuieux), causing forgetting or forgetfulness (early 16th cent.; French oblivieux).* If you are looking for an active verb meaning *(he) was unaware*, I don't think there is one.

Comment: [Here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248653/what-is-a-good-word-for-a-lack-of-knowledge-on-a-particular-subject-matter)'s a related one. I'm not considering yours a duplicate, since what you're asking for is a verb. But I doubt there is one, other than _miss_ or _overlook_, as has already been suggested, or perhaps _lack_, but that's quite wide. _Nescio_ would do the trick (whereof _nescient_ as @FumbleFingers suggested) but that's Latin...

Comment: I would tend to say "clueless about".

Comment: @HotLicks But I think *clueless about* has a quite different sense - it usually means lacking in knowledge or skill at something. *He is clueless with mathematical problems*. *Oblivious* tends to be about awareness. *She drank half a bottle of whisky over lunch, oblivious of the fact that she had to drive home*.

Comment: @WS2 - In my experience, "clueless" means being either unable or unwilling to know anything about the topic at hand.  "Ignorance" can be corrected with education, but not "cluelessness".

Comment: @Hot Licks MW and ODO present rather different definitions of *clueless*. We may have discovered that it is nuanced differently in America/Britain. MW: *completely or hopelessly bewildered,unaware, ignorant,or foolish*, - *clueless about what they want*. ODO: *having no knowledge, understanding or ability*. Clearly *unawareness* is absent from the British definition. Nothing in the OED to suggest *unawareness*, not even as a N.American usage. I am going to raise this as an OP.

Comment: @WS2 - Note that "clueless" is likely derived from "hasn't a clue", which implies something beyond simple ignorance.

Comment: @HotLicks Have you seen the discussion at [*What are the connotations of "clueless"*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360377/what-are-the-connotations-of-clueless/360412#comment838327_360412)?

Comment: @WS2 - I've seen the discussion but not read it through.

Comment: The minotaur was clueless. Theseus brought one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about *overlook* or *miss*?

M-W:

> *overlook*: to look past : miss
>
> [*miss*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miss): to fail to
>   comprehend, sense, or experience

Your example:

> Truth be told, he *overlooked* the answer himself.
>
> Truth be told, he *missed* the answer himself.

In both of these examples, he simply didn't see or notice the answer. No intentionality involved.

Note: @Irhala mentions *miss* in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

***[*to be unaware of*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/unaware)***

> *unaware*: not knowing that something exists, or not having knowledge or experience of something: *I was unaware of the risks involved.  Bowman was unaware that the car was gone.*

*(Cambridge Dictionary)*

Truth be told, he *was unaware of* the answer himself.