# What are the connotations of "clueless"?

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language, connotation, nuance, transatlantic-differences

As a result of a discussion with @Hot Licks on another post, it is apparent that his (American) understanding of the nuances associated with *clueless* is slightly different to my (British) understanding.

Reference to both Merriam Webster and Oxford Dictionaries would seem to confirm this difference.

**At issue is whether *clueless* is a synonym of *oblivious*. My inclination, which appears supported by the ODO is that *oblivious* is about forgetting or being unaware of something, whilst *clueless* is essentially about knowledge and ability.**

***Clueless*** is separately defined by:

ODO: *adj* *having no knowledge, understanding or ability*.

But MW has a longer definition:
*completely or hopelessly bewildered, unaware, ignorant, or foolish*

Referring to what some consider the fount of all knowledge, the OED, which addresses the entire corpus of English as used around the world, there is no mention, under *clueless*, of *unawareness*.

To me, to be *oblivious* means simply to be unaware. Even the greatest scholar could be *oblivious* of the fact that something was about to happen. But *clueless* to me suggests a lack of capacity, or knowledge, and it would be quite in error to say that *Einstein was clueless* even if it was that he did not realise he was about to be attacked by someone lurking in the shadows.

In Britain it would be an insult to call someone *clueless*, but not necessarily so with *oblivious*. Is that not the case in America?

Comment: Are you asking if clueless can be synonymous of oblivious in AmE?

Comment: @JOSH That is certainly how the discussion started. Hot Licks thinks it can. But to me they are not synonymous.

Comment: @WS2 I'm inclined to agree with you that *clueless* has to do with ability, not simply awareness. However, perhaps there is some middle ground to be found. In the *Einstein* example, one might say that he was clueless *about his surroundings*.

Comment: @Lawrence Which side of the pond do you speak for? In Britain I would take it as an insult to be called *clueless*.

Comment: @Lawrence But I do agree that it would be less of an insult to be *clueless* about something specific. e.g. My own children consider me *clueless* about computers and IT, but that I can accept. But it doesn't necessarily mean I am in any sense *oblivious*

Comment: [@WS2](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360377/what-is-the-meaning-of-clueless#comment838116_360377) I favour BrE. To be called *clueless* without further context *is* rather insulting, but to be *clueless about X* is a little less so. Although I don't speak for AmE, I wouldn't be surprised if it attached an implicit context of *social awareness* (or lack thereof) to the label *clueless*. E.g.: *Clueless in Seattle*.

Comment: @BoldBen Very well put. Why don't you supply that as an answer? I am waiting for someone, perhaps an American to provide a slightly different one.

Comment: In the American Alicia Silverstone *Clueless* movie -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clueless_(film) isn't the lead character oblivious  and unaware of 'real life'  but essentially intelligent and profound?

Comment: It could help to know if your discussion with the AmE speaker was about a specific usage context or just about the two words   in general terms.

Comment: @JOSH [This is where it was discussed](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360201/word-that-means-to-be-oblivious-to-but-not-on-purpose#comment838102_360201)

Comment: There is more than one sense of the word in American English. Both oblivious and stupid are accepted meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the term is not nearly as grievous an insult in the US as it apparently is in the UK, and can be used in situations where oblivious might also be used.

As the question is about some fairly subtle particulars of usage, and existing dictionary definitions aren't helpful in distinguishing between these usages, I will take the liberty of constructing a working definition to help structure the rest of my answer:

> ### Clueless, *adj.*
>
> Lacking knowledge or comprehension
>
> I. In a general domain
>
> > A. Due to
> >     incapacity
> >     B. Due to lack of experience with or exposure to existing evidence
>
> II. Of a specific fact, usually due to lack of evidence

In Sense I, cluelessness about a subject may result from either a (reparable) lack of experience or from an inability to comprehend. However, even in the more severe, lack-of-capacity case the person does not necessarily lack capacity in other areas of life and learning. Examples of this kind of usage:

> It's also very hilly, which should have been a clue for me about how
>   difficult this race was going to be, but as I said, I was **clueless** on
>   all aspects. The race only draws about 250 participants, and again, I
>   was **clueless** as to why, until it was too late to turn back.
>   —[Ileta
>   Coley, "Blood is Thicker than Water", *First Marathons: Personal
>   Encounters with the 26.2-mile Monster*, ed. Gail W. Kislevitz,
>   1999](https://books.google.com/books?id=RYPUtUOtAxIC&lpg=PA74&dq=%22i%20was%20clueless%22&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q=%22i%20was%20clueless%22&f=false)
>
> Despite himself, Dan laughed. He turned around and looked at me
>   affectionately. “You're the smartest woman I know, but you're
>   completely **clueless** about math, aren't you.” “Guilty as charged.” I
>   grinned.
>   —[Janice Kaplan, A Job to Kill For: A Lacy Fields Mystery,
>   2008](https://books.google.com/books?id=FBAc8E29hCQC&lpg=PA261&dq=%22clueless%20about%20math%22&pg=PA261#v=onepage&q=%22clueless%20about%20math%22&f=false)

Although this usage is not necessarily horribly insulting, neither is it quite the same as *oblivious*. However, the second sense comes much closer to being synonymous with oblivious.

In sense II, *clueless* can mean that the person lacks knowledge or awareness of a specific circumstance, which can be due to factors entirely beyond the individual's control. I would say that this at least comes very close to synonymy with *oblivious*. For example:

> “I'm under the impression you were **clueless** about the affair?” Trevor
>   once again offers a nod and states, “No sir. I had no idea about the
>   affair or the fact she was pregnant.”
>   —[Stephen Mitchell, *The
>   Forgotten House*, 2013](https://books.google.com/books?id=QE8WBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA99&dq=%22No%20sir.%20I%20had%20no%20idea%20about%20the%20affair%20or%20the%20fact%20she%20was%20pregnant.%22&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q=%22No%20sir.%20I%20had%20no%20idea%20about%20the%20affair%20or%20the%20fact%20she%20was%20pregnant.%22&f=false) (Trevor was *oblivious* to his wife's affair)
>
> And make no mistake...you will be judged and judged heartlessly by
>   those who are **clueless** as to what your life has been like as a
>   caregiver.
>   —[Sandra Savell, *Dear Clueless*, 2015](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q3sbBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA91&dq=%22clueless%20as%20to%22&pg=PA91#v=onepage&q=%22clueless%20as%20to%22&f=false) (Non-caregivers are likely to be *oblivious* to the realities of life as a caregiver)
>
> Suzie could see the steady crisscross traffic up ahead—late-night
>   motorists, coming and going, **clueless** to the danger speeding their
>   way.
>   —[David DeLee, *With Intent to Deceive*, 2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=fo-3CgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT7&dq=clueless%20%22to%20the%20danger%22&pg=PT7#v=onepage&q=clueless%20%22to%20the%20danger%22&f=false) (The motorists were *oblivious* to the danger speeding their way)

The following quote illustrates rather well some of the subtleties of the term's usage:

> Dr. Falmer was just as **clueless** as he'd hoped she would be, but it
>   wasn't the right kind of **clueless**. She wasn't a snob, intellectual
>   or social. She wasn't a fool, or an airhead like Marcey and Arrow. She
>   was just a pleasant, well-meaning, quietly dressed woman who probably
>   didn't have the faintest idea what she'd gotten herself into. Carl
>   Frank hadn't wanted to be the one to let her in on the secret.
>   —[Jane
>   Haddam, *Cheating at Solitaire: A Gregor Demarkian Novel*, 2008](https://books.google.com/books?id=lwBY9iVwJo0C&lpg=PA109&dq=clueless%20that%20she%20was%20cheating&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q=clueless%20that%20she%20was%20cheating&f=false)

The relative "insulting-ness" of the term might be judged to some extent by how often it is applied in the first person. Looking only at the *frequency* of use within the American English corpus ([here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20was%20clueless&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20was%20clueless%3B%2Cc0)) and British English corpus ([here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20was%20clueless&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20was%20clueless%3B%2Cc0)) on Google Ngrams, we see that "I was clueless" is five times as common for US writers as for British writers. Of course standard disclaimers about Ngrams apply, but the numbers are at least suggestive.

[image: "I was clueless" side-by-side comparison, American and British corpuses]

---

I don't think that this belongs in the body of the answer, but in looking for clues to differences in usage I found that the most common word to precede *clueless* in the American corpus is *was*, and following the path of most common following words it appears that the most common phrase containing the word is likely *was clueless about how to*. To me, this phrase is suggestive of a lack of knowledge that can be rectified. In the British corpus, on the other hand, the most common word to precede *clueless* is *a*; *a clueless___* looks very much as if it is going to be an insult.

(To find this, I used a wildcard search to find the most common word preceding *clueless* in each corpus—"* clueless"—and then added wildcards to the end of the most common phrase until Ngram returned no answers. That is, "was clueless *" in American English gives "was clueless about" as most common, etc. until "was clueless about how to *" gives no results. In the British English corpus, "a clueless *" is the dead end.)

Comment: Very nice. (But check *I don't think know* in the penultimate paragraph.)

Comment: This is a very impressive piece of work and I have no hesitation in awarding you the "correct answer". I have thought about each of the six quotations you have given, all of which I assume are American in origin. Kaplan's (and possibly Savell's) use of *clueless* is quintessentially the British use. In all the other cases I don't believe a British author would use *clueless*. My estimate is that Coley's would be *uninformed*, Mitchell *no knowledge of*, Savell, De Lee & Haddam *oblivious*. But this proves the point of my question. Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  "Oblivious" is not used very much in the US and is generally used in the sense of "totally ignorant of the events discussed".  This ignorance might result from, eg, having been stranded on a desert island for 10 years.  "Clueless" is used in several senses, probably most often in a jocular sense (the "I'm clueless" cases, especially), but also in a darker sense ("Mr Trump is totally clueless with regard to foreign policy").  In this latter sense the meaning is "completely and willfully ignorant" or "incapable of understanding".

Comment: @HotLicks, I'm certainly not saying they mean exactly the same thing (do any two words?), just that they have at least one definition each where they overlap. The overlap is clearest in the context of something going on which other people know about or which eventually catches the person unawares. Google "clueless about the affair" and "oblivious to the affair" and you'll find similar quotes, though *oblivious* is more common. Other situations where I'd expect overlap would be when discussing, say, office politics or undercurrents of social interactions or what kids these days are into.

Comment: My main point is that "That guy is clueless" is a slightly more polite way of saying "That guy is a fucking idiot".  As such it carries a much more negative connotation than "That guy is oblivious".

Comment: @HotLicks I think mileage may vary on that, and context will usually be the deciding factor. I would not use a bare "he's clueless" with the connotations you ascribe; to me, it is much milder. Perhaps because my primary point of reference is the [1995 Alicia Silverstone film *Clueless*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112697/) —that's probably not unusual for American women of my generation, but I imagine your primary point of reference is different.

Answer (score 6):

I don't believe that they are synonymous. Someone with no knowledge of domestic plumbing might be *clueless* when it came to stopping water running through his house from a failed pipe, but he certainly would not be *oblivious* to it. A fully qualified and experienced plumber, however, might be *oblivious* to a leak under his floorboards even though he was quite capable of fixing it if he knew about it.

Comment: I suspect you are succumbing to the etymological fallacy.

Comment: @HotLicks Not at all, I'm using the words according to their current usage. [This definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oblivious) supports my use of 'oblivious' and [this one](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/clueless) my use of 'clueless'.